# Storing multiple profile types in an SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

OK, so this might seem a weird question. I am using C# ASP.NET MVC to develop a membership system and I've got my members information stored with all of their details but I need each member to have a job profile stored in the database. This contains different kinds of things like qualifications, accreditations etc.  Obviously, different job types will need to store different data types

I was going to just create a dozen or so different profiles for each job type and assign a record in an appropriate table to a user but this still seems rather clunky, (though I guess it may be the only choice I have).

I'm wondering if anyone can recommend or tell me of another way that this might be possible without cluttering up the DB with a million different tables?

Comment: I provided one possible option as an answer, but are you sure your different job types would have different data types?  Obviously I don't know your requirements, but all job types would have Title, Description, Pay Grade, stuff like that would be the same.  Your qualifications and accreditation lists would be just normal relational one-to-many tables.

Comment: I think XML might be the way to go. You see, I need to store specific information for users in a specific job type.  For example, One of the work sectors is "Aerospace" and there are 2 job categories in there being Engineer and Pilot. Obviously an Engineer and Pilot have two completely different skill sets and each has varying qualification levels in that field.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to store the job profile meta-data as XML.  Sql-Server handles XML datatype quite nicely, or you can handle the serialization in your c#.  You could also store the data as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `XML` column to store profile data as xml formatted information in SqlServer, but if there is a chance of change I would recommend you take a look at NoSql DBs and Document style DBs like Redis or MongoDB that you can store each user profile data individually and may load the data to a full text searcher like Lucene for further search.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the end in mind.

- Who would want to query what pieces of information?
- What would be the easiest way to get at that data?

For Example: I am looking for all the members who can do X or have worked on Y, etc... How would I want the data to be organized so I can easily get an answer to that question.

Even if you put all the data elements into a document type container (xml,json,etc) - you should have those internal elements defined with searching in mind.